# Kohana v3.30 subfolders routing

Tags: frameworks, routes, kohana

I've a small problem with subfolders routing, it's a lot of questions abaut routing in kohana, but I wrote it all, and I still have a problem, I add in boostrap this lines :

```
Route::set('admin', 'folder(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
'directory' => 'folder',
'controller' => 'test',
'action' => 'pokaz',
 ));
```

I have folder in my controller folder (application/Controller/folder), my controller :

```
class Controller_Folder_Test extends Controller {
public function action_pokaz() {
    echo "dasdsadsad";
   }
 }
```

When i writing this url: 
1. http://example.com/kohana/index.php/test/pokaz - (Kohana - not found url)
2. http://example.com/kohana/index.php/folder/test/pokaz - (Kohana - not found url)
3. without /index.php/ - 404 Not found - Apache

So i really don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: let me see your bootstrap.php

Answer (score 1):

ok it's working, i changed the folder name from "folder" on "Folder" and thats all :D Thx for help anyway ;]